# Get XML child element values and append to parent during xml parsing

Tags: python, xml

I have a requirement to append children data to the parent in a hierarchy. The term may be flatten data to one parent level which is at the end of the hierarchy. I don't want to hard code the parent name  for whose children needs to be flattened. The structure of the xml hierarchy is consistent. To Sum up the requirement as per below example is the children of Properties element should have data from their sub child (example 'element') if any present. if there are any multiple subchilds need to show them in parent seperated by comma

Sample Data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xml:base="https://aciww.sharepoint.com/sites/AIIMOpwa/DASHBOARD%20DATA%20TEST/_api/">
   <id>440621ab-ccb9-4dd8-9a26-75fcb74dbf07</id>
   <title />
   <updated>2017-12-08T14:22:48Z</updated>
   <entry m:etag="&quot;1&quot;">
      <id>b3e30263-cead-40ef-8d2c-c790b433bef7</id>
      <title />
      <updated>2017-12-08T14:22:48Z</updated>
      <author>
         <name />
      </author>
      <content type="application/xml">
         <m:properties>
            <d:Workstream_x0020_Lead_x0028_s_x0Id m:type="Collection(Edm.Int32)">
               <d:element>18</d:element>
           </d:Workstream_x0020_Lead_x0028_s_x0Id>
            <d:Workstream_x0020_Lead_x0028_s_x0StringId m:type="Collection(Edm.String)">
               <d:element>18</d:element>
            </d:Workstream_x0020_Lead_x0028_s_x0StringId>
            <d:Functional_x0020_Program_x0020_LId m:type="Collection(Edm.Int32)">
               <d:element>18</d:element>
            </d:Functional_x0020_Program_x0020_LId>
            <d:Functional_x0020_Program_x0020_LStringId m:type="Collection(Edm.String)">
               <d:element>18</d:element>
               <d:element>333</d:element>
            </d:Functional_x0020_Program_x0020_LStringId>
         </m:properties>
      </content>
   </entry>
</feed>
```

Please find the code which returns all the elements in Serial format i mean parents and then the child.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree


tree = etree.parse('CR2.xml') # Please change the location to xml file

def removeNS(tag) :
    if tag.find('}') == -1 :
        return tag
    else:
        return tag.split('}', 1)[1]


for child in tree.iter():
       if (str(child).find('entry')>0):
           for child1 in child.iter():
                  if (str(child1).find('content')>0):
                    for child2 in child1.iter():
                        if(str(child2).find('properties')>0):
                            for child3 in child2.iter():
                                     print {removeNS(child3.tag):child3.text}
```

Expected Result

```
{'properties': '\n            '}
{'Workstream_x0020_Lead_x0028_s_x0Id': '18'}
{'Workstream_x0020_Lead_x0028_s_x0StringId': '18'}
{'Functional_x0020_Program_x0020_LId': '18'}
{'Functional_x0020_Program_x0020_LStringId': '18,333'}
```

Actual result  i get is shown below

```
{'properties': '\n            '}
{'Workstream_x0020_Lead_x0028_s_x0Id': None}
{'element': '18'}
{'Workstream_x0020_Lead_x0028_s_x0StringId': '\n               '}
{'element': '18'}
{'Functional_x0020_Program_x0020_LId': '\n               '}
{'element': '18'}
{'Functional_x0020_Program_x0020_LStringId': '\n               '}
{'element': '18'}
{'element': '333'}
```

Comment: this xml is giving error in parsing , paste correct xml

Comment: Pankaj, i am able to parse the same file copying it from here. I am using Python 2.7 for the above code.